# read key value from .ini file without section header

Tags: c#, ini

I am trying to write c# code to read key value from an ini file which doesnot contain a section header. As

```
 private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,       string key,string def, StringBuilder retVal,int size,string filePath);
```

function does not work in this case(as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686281/read-ini-file-which-does-not-have-any-section)) ,I tried to create another ini file with section header inserted . Then the GetPrivateProfileString function was used to read the key value. The ini file is getting created as expected, but the function is giving null value as result. Where have i gone wrong?

The code snippet is given below

```
//someFilePath contains .ini file 
string userFilePath = "someFilePath";
string sectionName = "TempSectionHeader";
string copyFile = "text.ini";
if (File.Exists(userFilePath))
{   
       if(File.Exists(copyFile))
       {
           File.Delete(copyFile);
       }

       File.AppendAllText("text.ini", "["+ sectionName + "]");
       string contents = File.ReadAllText(userFilePath);
       contents = contents.Replace("\0", "");
       File.AppendAllText(copyFile, "\r\n");
       File.AppendAllText(copyFile, contents);
       installName = ReadValueFromINIFile(sectionName, "installName", copyFile);
       MessageBox.Show(installName);
}
```

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file helps.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. The linked post has a nice Linq answer by dtb, that is probably hard to top. - Also instead of `File.Exists(userFilePath)` why not `Directory.Exists(userFilePath)` ??

Answer (score 1):

It's the path that is passed to GetPrivateProfileString that is wrong. Try using:

```
string installName = ReadValueFromINIFile(sectionName, "installName", Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, copyFile));
```

Comment: Thanks. The path passed to GetPrivateProfileString was  wrong `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,copyFile) worked for me`